# How to quickly scroll to the bottom of a document

Tags: word

I opened a Word (docx) document in my OneDrive folder. There are more than 60 pages and the content will keep growing every day. Whenever I want to read the latest content, it takes me so long to scroll to the bottom.

How can I do it quickly? Any tips please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an automatic summary in your Word document.

In this case you can tap in the option "Outline" in the bottom menu and choose which place you want to jump.

[image]

Comment: Technically this is not *scrolling* to the bottom...

Comment: Actually it was just a comment. but someone suggested it should be a real answer.